# Hide text based on country

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking to hide text to only web visitors from the United States, everyone else needs to see the text, this is what I have so far... Any help you can give me is MUCH appreciated!!

```js
$.ajax('https://freegeoip.net/json/')
  .done(function (e) {
  $('.myclass').eq(e.country_code === 'US' ? 0 : 1).show();
});
```

```css
.myclass {
    display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="myclass"> <p>Customers are responsible for all international duties upon arrival. Please check your local government agency for these costs.</p></div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So, since the AJAX call will return the country code. Use CSS to hide the block, Then write a CSS class for .US that displays the element, using javascript append the country code as a class, this will make the block appear for US and nothing else.

```
$.ajax('https://freegeoip.net/json/')
  .done(function (e) {
  $('.myclass').addClass(e.country_code);
});
```

.

```
myclass {
    display: none;
    }
.myclass.US {
    display: block;
    }
```

You can make other countries make the block appear by doing as follows:

```
 .myclass.US,.myclass.GB,.myclass.BR {
      display: block;
 }
```